# Different tokens names for non-parameterized and parameterized statements OR how to jump to previous token with RuleLexer

Tags: java, antlr4

How to achieve different token names for the following examples:

```
#someNameAttribute //where #someNameAttribute should be assigned to IDENTIFIER lexer rule
#someNameAttribute("2a3a796e-9870-4b88-9f2d-383eb9566613", 10) // where #someNameAttribute should be assigned to PARAMETERIZED_IDENTIFIER since we faced with parenthesis
```

Grammar I have right now(but it always assigned to IDENTIFIER):

```
grammar Rule;

ruleExpression
    : identifierExpression EOF | parameterizedIdentifierExpression EOF
    ;

identifierExpression
    : IDENTIFIER
    ;

parameterizedIdentifierExpression
    : PIDENTIFIER LPAREN UUID DELIMETER NUMERIC RPAREN
    ;

DELIMETER           : ',';
LPAREN              : '(';
RPAREN              : ')';
UUID                : '"'[0-9a-fA-F]+'-'[0-9a-fA-F]+'-'[1-5][0-9a-fA-F]+'-'[89abAB][0-9a-fA-F]+'-'[0-9a-fA-F]+'"';
NUMERIC             : [0-9]+ ( '.' [0-9]+ )? ;
IDENTIFIER          : '#' [a-zA-Z$_] [a-zA-Z$_0-9]*;
// PARAMETERIZED_IDENTIFIER         : { behind(LPAREN) }? IDENTIFIER;  // Tried to use semantic predicate but no luck. Might be used it wrong way
WS                  : [ \r\t\u000C\n]+ -> skip;
```

Or if it's possible somehow to check next token on parenthesis after #someNameAttribute from Java code - will be glad to hear how to do that. I tried this way as well however RuleLexer.nextToken() allow me to check next token but I cannot jump to previous token again to proceed the whole statement(starting to lose some tokens due to it).

How I can achieve to predict what token name to assign or how to jump to previous token using RuleLexer from Java code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this (only works for Java):

```
grammar Rule;

any           : .*? EOF;

LPAREN        : '(';
RPAREN        : ')';
UUID          : '"'[0-9a-fA-F]+'-'[0-9a-fA-F]+'-'[1-5][0-9a-fA-F]+'-'[89abAB][0-9a-fA-F]+'-'[0-9a-fA-F]+'"';
NUMERIC       : [0-9]+ ( '.' [0-9]+ )? ;
PIDENTIFIER   : IDENTIFIER {_input.LA(1) == '('}?;
IDENTIFIER    : '#' [a-zA-Z$_] [a-zA-Z$_0-9]*;
WS            : [ \r\t\u000C\n]+ -> skip;
OTHER         : . ;
```

In case spaces are allowed between the identifier and the `(`, do something like this:

```
grammar Rule;

@lexer::members {
  boolean spacesAndOpenParenAhead() {
    for (int i = 1; ; i++) {
      char ch = (char)_input.LA(i);
      if (ch == '(') {
        return true;
      }
      else if (ch != ' ' && ch != '\t' && ch != '\r' && ch != '\n') {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
}

...

PIDENTIFIER         : IDENTIFIER {spacesAndOpenParenAhead()}?;
IDENTIFIER          : '#' [a-zA-Z$_] [a-zA-Z$_0-9]*;
```

When I run the code below on both my example grammars:

```java
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String source = "#someNameAttribute\n" +
                "#someNameAttribute(\"2a3a796e-9870-4b88-9f2d-383eb9566613\", 10)";

        RuleLexer lexer = new RuleLexer(CharStreams.fromString(source));

        CommonTokenStream stream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        stream.fill();

        for (Token t : stream.getTokens()) {
            System.out.printf("%-20s `%s`%n",
                    RuleLexer.VOCABULARY.getDisplayName(t.getType()),
                    t.getText().replace("\n", "\\n"));
        }
    }
}
```

the following is printed on my console:

```
IDENTIFIER           `#someNameAttribute`
PIDENTIFIER          `#someNameAttribute`
'('                  `(`
UUID                 `"2a3a796e-9870-4b88-9f2d-383eb9566613"`
OTHER                `,`
NUMERIC              `10`
')'                  `)`
```

Comment: #someNameAttribute("2a3a796e-9870-4b88-9f2d-383eb9566613", 10) - works, but
#someNameAttribute - not working, still assigned to PIDENTIFIER

Comment: I get the expected result (first is `IDENTIFIER` and after it a `PIDENTIFIER`). Check my edited answer.

Comment: Spaces not allowed between attribute name and parenthesis. I copy-pasted your first option and got PIDENTIFIER - PIDENTIFIER - LPAREN - UUID - DELIMETER - NUMERIC - RPAREN by some reason.

Comment: Added the grammar I used.

Comment: Looks my ANTLR v4 plugin for Intellij doesn't understand semantic predicates. I see correct assignment from code. Thanks!